# How to format a JTextField so words don't cutoff?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a JTextField which cuts off my input making the sentence go on past the bounds instead of 
starting a new line every 5 words or so. I have tried in the past **this** which has worked for a JLabel but not for JtextField:

```
String html1 = "<html><body style='width: ";
String html2 = "px'>";
labell.setText(html1+"300"+html2+content);
```

Comment: JTextFields shouldn't have "new lines". Do you instead mean a JTextArea?

Comment: Nope, a JTextField. And I know it doesn't automatically do new lines, this is what I want to achieve.

Comment: Why? Why use a square peg for a round hole when round pegs exist and are **very** easy to use? Why not simply use a JTextArea for your multi-line text component?

Comment: Just tried, this doesn't do it any different, the sentence still goes off the right border..

Comment: @user2855405 You need to configure the text area to perform word wrapping.  You probably should also add the `JTextArea` to a `JScrollPane`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)

You may also want to take a look at

- [`JTextArea#setLineWrap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setLineWrap(boolean))
- [`JTextArea#setWrapStyleWord`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setWrapStyleWord(boolean))
- [`JTextArea#setRows`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setRows(int))
- [`JTextArea#setColumns`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setColumns(int))